# Store value to variable in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jq

"$emails" has the array of values, i want to parse the values from it, To do it, i am using the [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq). if i do below command

```
echo "$emails" | ./jq '.total_rows'
```

i could get the value i.e 4, i want to store the returned results into some variable,

```
total_rows="$emails" | ./jq '.total_rows'
```

but total_rows has no value.

```
echo $total_rows
```

How do store the returned result into variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the right quotation, like this:

```
total_rows=`echo "$emails" | ./jq '.total_rows'`
```

The `` will execute the command and give `total_rows` the value of it, so whatever would be the output of

```
echo "$emails" | ./jq '.total_rows'
```

will so be stored in `total_rows`.

As mentioned in the comments by Tom Fenech, it is better to use `$()` for command substitution. It provides a better readability. So what you can do is:

```
total_rows=$(echo "$emails" | ./jq '.total_rows')
```

Comment: I would recommend using `$( )` over backticks for command substitutions. Also, in bash you can use `total_rows=$(./jq '.total_rows' <<<"$emails")`.

Comment: Notice also you cannot add white space total_rows = ` doesn't work